# Tensorflow-MKL giving Errors on 3D data

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, intel-mkl, intel-dnn

I am training a model to perform volumetric segmentation (3D data). I am training on CPU due to the size of the input data. I am using a anaconda environment with tensorflow-mkl and keras. When I train the model, I get an `error` :

```
"tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Value for attr 'data_format' of "NDHWC" is not in the list of allowed values: "NHWC", "NCHW"
```

However, on their github it says it works on volumetric segmentation (https://github.com/intel/mkl-dnn). How may I resolve this issue so I can train my 3D-Unet with `mkl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to update tensorflow to 1.8.0 version.
Hope this solves your issue.